# Laravel Sentry limits

Tags: laravel, limits, cartalyst-sentry

Anybody know how to get limited number of sentry users. I have admin panel in my laravel application and I make a user management. For display data (groups table, user table, permission table, ...) I use jqgrid. So if I have half million users I want to get limited list of users with specific data.

For use limitation in Laravel, I use standard function *skip* and *take*, but I cannot use these method on Sentry findAllUsers().

What solution is the best in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways, one of them is to get an empty Sentry user model, which is based on Eloquent:

```
$model = Sentry::getUserProvider()->getEmptyUser();
```

And use it as you would with Eloquent:

```
$all = $model->all();

$paginated = $model->paginate();

$selected = $model->where('age', '<', 21)->get();
```